# How do you refer to functions in a crate from an exported crate macro in rust?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to write some debugging helper macros. So I create a crate to hold all of them, and referred to the crate externally using phase(plugin):

```
#[cfg(test)]
#[phase(plugin)]
extern crate debugging;
```

That successfully exports the macros into the crate.

However, for some of these tools I wanted to invoke functions from the crate, for example:

```
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! trace(
  {$($arg:tt)*} => {
    {
      extern crate debug;
      let s = ::macros::logger(); // <---- This!
      let _ = s.write_line(format_args!(::std::fmt::format, $($arg)*).as_slice());
    }
  };
)
```

Using a global namespace, ie. ::macros::logger works if the macro is placed into macros.rs and imported from the crate root of a crate.

However, what I'm trying to achieve here is the same thing when the macro has to invoke a call from its own crate.

If the macro expanded correctly, I believe:

```
let s = ::crate_name::logger();
```

Would be the way to do it, but the crate with the macro cannot refer to itself by name in this way. It generates errors like:

```
src/macros.rs:52:15: 52:20 error: failed to resolve. Maybe a missing `extern crate debugging`?
src/macros.rs:52       let s = ::debugging::logger();
                               ^~~~~
src/macros.rs:49:1: 56:2 note: in expansion of trace!
src/file.rs:26:11: 26:29 note: expansion site
```

...and finally just so we're completely clear about what I'm trying to do:

```
crate debugging:
   lib.rs
     fn logger() 
   macros.rs
     macro_rules! trace(...) // <--- Trying to figure out what to put here...

crate foo:
   lib.rs
     #[phase(plugin)] extern crate debugging;
     fn test_thing() {
       trace!("{}", ...); // <--- So debugging::logger() is invoked here
     }
```

So, is there some way to do this from a macro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now, the correct thing to do is use an absolute path like that and then do some reexports in the original crate so that path resolves.

I.e. in `lib.rs` put

```
mod debugging {
    pub use logger;
}
```

which reexports the top level function `logger` as `debugging::logger`. There is work being done that makes this saner, e.g. `$crate` which expands to name of the crate from which the macro came (when used externally), or to nothing (when used internally); this isn't necessarily the final design, but it is improving.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who finds this, it's worth noting that you cannot use from a crate marked with phase plugin. To import the symbols locally (as per the accepted answer), you need to do this:

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod debug {
  #[phase(plugin)]
  extern crate debugging;
  extern crate debugging;
  pub use self::debugging::debug;
}
```

Notice the double extern crate debugging, because typically you wouldn't want to export a syntax extension module as part of the code.